# casting a cgo array into a slice

Tags: go, cgo

At the moment I do this for casting a CGO array of doubles into a slice of float64:

```
doubleSlc := [6]C.double{}

// Fill doubleSlc

floatSlc := []float64{float64(doubleSlc[0]), float64(doubleSlc[1]), float64(doubleSlc[2]),
                      float64(doubleSlc[3]), float64(doubleSlc[4]), float64(doubleSlc[5])}
```

Is there a less cumbersome way of doing the same thing? I suppose this can also be seen as a general way of casting between slices/arrays of different types in Go.

Comment: The main problem here is casting the array into a new type, not the array to slice same type transformation...

Comment: Sorry, missed that. there's no way other than a loop, but of course no need to manually do it one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the normal and safe way of doing this:

```
c := [6]C.double{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
fs := make([]float64, len(c))
for i := range c {
        fs[i] = float64(c[i])
}
```

Or you could cheat unportably and do this:

```
c := [6]C.double{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
cfa := (*[6]float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&c))
cfs := cfa[:]
```

If `C.double` and `float64` are the same underlying type we can take a pointer to the C.double array, unsafely cast it to a pointer to a same size float64 array, then take a slice of that array.

Of course it's called `unsafe` for a very good reason.